# I have to use different syntax then my friend does. Where can I change that?

Tags: syntax-error

I wrote some code in C# that looks like this:

```
string path = "Accounts\accounts1.txt";
```

but for some reason it only works with:

```
string path = "Accounts/account1.txt";
```

so I published it run the exe and it works on my pc. I tried it on my wife's laptop and of course it won't work because it is not \ .

A few days earlier I tried a bit windows fonds and there I got problem changing the backColor. My friend can write `50,60,70` for RGB value but I have to use `50;60;70` or I get a error message.

We both use Microsoft Visual Studio 2019.

Is the syntax different in other languages (human)? Because my Windows is german but I use the English package in MVS19.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\ is a special character in strings in c#. This could be your problem. You could try:

```
string path = @"Accounts\accounts1.txt";
```

or:

```
string path = "Accounts\\accounts1.txt";
```

Comment: OMG. 
yes thats the problem. now with \\ it works. still curios do you know why it also works with / . i mean it shouldnt. and do you know by any chance why i have to wire ; and not , in windows fonds?

Comment: I would guess it works because linux uses /. And it is being forgiving and allowing you to use either. Is it Windows Forms you are using?

Comment: for the  \ problem it was console app in C#. windows form was only the , ; problem.

Comment: I would need to see the code to understand. Color.FromArgb(10, 245, 10) is the usual way to get a color from RGB values I believe

Comment: i dont even know where the  code in forms would be . i tryd to change the value in the propertis menu of the window. ou could open a new microsoft forms in MVS and try it yourself. iwaas following this tut https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vYDyGxoq9JU&t=187s its arround minute 1 and in backCollor. if i typ in 46,51,73 it gives this error: 46,51,73 is not a valid value for Int32. using; instead of , works. but if i dont know  the cause of that error i can not tell if it matters or not so i stoppet working on the forms and work instead on console app.

Comment: Ya, adding 46,51,73 works for me I'm afraid